# How many times does a user use the app within the selected time period?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to determine how often a user used the website/app within a timespan on the website of google analytics?

Let's say i want to know how many of my users returned at least 2 times within the last 30days.

*As far as i know the `count of sessions` is not an option here since it does not give the information required for this.*

How to i archive this and can i archive that i get a breakdown of that like: `1,2,3,4,5,5-10,10-20...` within the given time period?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to set up/monitor cookies via Google's [analytics.js library.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage) According to the docs, analytics.js can do the following:

1. Determine which domain to measure
2. Distinguish unique users
3. Throttle the request rate
4. **Remember the number and time of previous visits**
5. Remember traffic source information
6. **Determine the start and end of a session**
7. Remember the value of visitor-level custom variables